# How to wrap a text in Object tag

Tags: html, css

I have a web page where I am embedding some text that comes from AWS S3 object. This object contains some simple text string. However I want this text to be wrapped automatically to the visible window.  I have defined text-annotation class shown below. But right now I always get horizontal scroll bar and text doesn't auto formatted so the paragraph content get auto-wrapped. How do I

```
<object class="text-annotation" type="text/html" data="url-to-s3-source"">
<p>backup content</p>
</object>



.text-annotation {
    border: 1px solid #e1e1e8;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r8YQ8/  pls edit this to show us what is not working

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/snijsure/r8YQ8/2/ where my text from amazon S3 is not getting wrapped up but I see horizontal scroll bar.